# How to Alert Broadcast notifications in Laravel Echo from Pusher

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm trying to alert Laravel Broadcast notifications from pusher using Laravel Echo listener when User is add a vacancy to the database according to my case. I don't need to show notifications on the default notification bar with vue.js. Simply i need to alert when some user add vacancy to the database.  But Unfortunately I can't figure it out. Is there any way to do this ?

**This is my Notification Class**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Notifications;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
 use App\Employer;
 use App\Vacancy;

 class vacancyAdd extends Notification
 {
  use Queueable;
  public $vacancy;

 public function __construct($vacancy)
 {
    $this->vacancy = $vacancy;
 }


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database','broadcast'];
}

public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
      'vacancy' => $this->vacancy      
    ];
}

public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'vacancy' => $this->vacancy
    ]);
}
}
```

**This is my app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

        window.Vue = require('vue');

        /**
         * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
         * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
         * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
         */

        Vue.component('ExampleComponent', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            created(){
                Echo.private('App.User.'+window.Laravel.userId).notification((notification) => {
                    console.log('Notification received ', notification);
                    alert(notification);
                });
            }

        });
```

**My Pusher Debug Console**

[Pusher Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXKc4.png)
Can you please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact issue you are facing? There doesn't appear to be any errors in your code and the publish event is working as the events are showing the debug console.

Comment: `alert(notification);` is not working. I want to alert when notification arrives

Comment: Does your console log the `Notification received' message as expected?

Comment: No. It doesn't seen